# The volume of an $n$-lattice

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry

I'm reading a proof of Minkowski's theorem and have a question on a detail. Let $M \in \text{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$ and let $\Lambda_M := M(\mathbb{Z}^n)$. The claim is that $\text{Vol}(\Lambda_M) = |\det M|$, which I think implies $\text{Vol}(\mathbb{Z}^n) = 1$. Am I correct? Why is the volume of the $n$-lattice $1$? Are we considering $\mathbb{Z}^n$ as a unit $n$-cube rather than as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$?

$\textbf{EDIT:}$ Is the reason because $\text{Vol}(\mathbb{Z}^n) = \det I_n = 1$?

Comment: $\text{Vol}(\mathbb{Z}^n)$ is a shorthand for $\text{Vol}(\mathbb{R}^n/\mathbb{Z}^n)$, the volume of the corresponding fundamental domain. The latter $\mathbb{R}^n/\mathbb{Z}^n$ is topologically a $n$-torus and the volume of it ( the one induced by metric on $\mathbb{R}^n$ canonically ) is 1.

Comment: Great, thank you (extra characters).